# unable to connect with database

Tags: symfony

I have downloded some code of `symfony` from `github`. I have configured all the things. 
I have created the database using command

```
 php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

I have created the database also but when I am trying to log in or register then I am not registering when I am looking at `profiler` then it shows that no query has been executed. what should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your parameters_dev.ini file inside config and confirm whether the setting s are correct or not ? have you already created the database? can you upload some more code for details?

Comment: yep the thing are correct in `parameter.ini`  database_driver   = pdo_mysql
    database_host     = localhost
    database_port     =
    database_name     = symfony
    database_user     = root
    database_password = 123456

Comment: give the port 3306 and then check

Comment: what error exactly you are getting , Can you add the code which you are trying to run?

Comment: actually this is a simple register and login process. when i am trying to register or login, as i clickd on submit then it gives error `Error in signing up, Please try again`. and in symfony `profile` it shows that no query has been executed so i think that it is not connected with database

Comment: when you submit the form check whether some data is going in the form or not ? and show me how u are writning the user insertion query?

Comment: $logger = $this->get('logger');
$request = $this->get('request');
$email = $request->request->get('email', '');
$password = $request->request->get('password', '');
$user_id = user_exist($email, $password,$this->get('database_connection'), $logger);if ($user_id != null){$result = array('responseCode'=>200, "success"=>"true")$result = json_encode($result);$response=new Response($result, 200);$response->headers->set('Content-type', 'application/json');
     $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('formbuilder_login', $user_id));
 }else{
     $result = array('responseCode'=>200, "error"=>"true")

Comment: Did you create the Entity classes for your database tables? Try to use doctorine for queries... Have a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: but its not necessary that i should create entity. with out entity i can create database. its running on my another system when it has been designed. i have taken the code and mysql files from there

Comment: its running on that system perfectly

Comment: If you have taken the code and just copy pasted than it can be the problem of symfony2  bundle ... You need to create a new bundle with exactly the one you have in your copied code... Create a new bundle and then copy on ly the controller and views, Best will be to check out the bundle from other system if possible

Comment: Are you sure that your bundle is registerd in AppKernel.php file?

Comment: yep, that why i am able to see the login and register screen

Answer (score 1):

Check your port and try type 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in parameters file, it's strange but it works for me.

Comment: i am getting the same problem again

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the schema after you created the database?

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

What do the logs (`app/logs/dev.log` or `app/logs/prod.log`) say?